# Can I use a Docker container to build an Android application using Xamarin

Tags: android, visual-studio, docker, xamarin

Reading the Microsoft documentation on Docker and containerized application development, it doesn't clearly describe what you can and can't do.

As a developer one compelling use case for containers would be the ability to have my actual development environment within the container, so that when I need to work on a particular project on a different physical machine I can just install the necesary container from the container registry and away I go.

The Microsoft documentation seems to imply, without actually stating it unequivocally, that this is indeed possible for Dotnet Core applications, but makes no mention of what other applications types (if any) this is possible for.

To give a concrete example. I'd like to build an Android application using Xamarin. I'd rather not have to globally install a particular version of the Android SDK, nor would I like to install multiple global Android SDKs in order to switch between them when working on different projects. Instead I'd like to use an Android build environment in a Docker container.

Is this possble? If so is there any documentation anywhere describing how I might go about this?

If it's not possible and as I developer I still have to install an entire build environment for every type of project I work on locally, on every dev machine I use, then as a developer I don't really see what use Docker is to me. In that case it seems to be primarily a ProdOps tool.